# Spring Integration SMB is invalid on linux(CentOS 7)

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, centos7, smb

I used `Spring Integration SMB` to upload local files to `Windows shared folder`, and I can run normally in the local windows environment and idea, but when I put the application into a jar package and put it on the `CentOS 7` server, I found that it failed, without any Integration related output logs, it just didn't work. What causes this?

I have installed the smb service on the server, and port `445` is enabled. `smbclient` and `mount -t cifs` can be used to access and mount the smb service. I have configured the minimum and maximum SMB version numbers to ensure that `smb2` or `SMB2-3` does not work

help~!!!!

Comment: Turn on `debug` logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` to see more info when you interact with your Spring Integration solution.

Comment: I didn't find any useful log output

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved!!!

The problem is not in the `linux` or `windows` system environment, but when packaging jars on windows, there is a problem. The `shade` plug-in I use for fat jar packaging affects the `bouncy castle` signature that `jcifs` relies on. As a result, `the JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC error occurred. I repackaged the independent jar package and copied the lib package to a lib directory separately. After starting the jar, I successfully ran and uploaded the file.

However, I still don't know why there is no error in `Integration`. I got the error information by directly using `Jcifs` under Integration dependency. Maybe I didn't configure the `errorChannel` of Integration properly, right

Comment: Good to know that you have figured out the problem. I wander why Spring Boot uber jar doesn't work for you. Re. error: it would be great to see some logs from your application in process. Anyway that sounds like different SO thread...